# Where to put constants shared by multiple files with package scope?

Tags: go, package, constants

I have a Go package that declares and uses some constants in `file1.go`. Now I add a new file to the package, `file2.go`, which refers to constants in `file1.go`.

Would you move the shared constants into a new file, like `consts.go`, since they don't "belong" to one file or the other? Or do you leave them in `file1.go` and assume that someone looking at `file2.go` can use their IDE or editor or grep to locate the shared constants?

Comment: Globals belong to a package. This is pretty much the reverse of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253939/global-variable-private-to-file/45254046#45254046 So basically, you organize your packages as you see fit. In case of a package you plan to publish, either use const.go or `<packageName>.go`: both clean and clear enough.

Comment: A) Stop using underscores in your filenames. Underscores are used to separate the *_test.go files and you shouldn't use it for "normal" names. B) Files have no real meaning in a Go package: Everything is package based and all files contribute equally to the package. How you split a large package into files is up to you, your taste and may change.

Comment: There are no underscores in the actual file names. I’ve renamed them file1.go and file2.go so that this isn’t distracting. They’re part of the same package, and both refer to the same few constants.

Comment: Markus, this is a single large package, where file1 and file2 cover two different areas but share a couple constants. It sounds like const.go would work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `const.go` file is an idiomatic way, see Go standard library.
For example see: `math/const.go`

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen math/const.go, but wondered if it was an exception and had more to do with mathematical constants. It looks like they have a couple const.go files in the crypto libraries too.